# Performance issues with AMD IOMMU on

Tags: ati, amd-processor

I had a hard time installing Ubuntu on my system. The motherboard I'm using is the **Gigabyte GA-970A-D3** with **AMD FX6300**. I tried to install elementaryOS, Ubuntu 12.04 and Ubuntu 14.04, and for all three of them, when the IOMMU is turned on in the BIOS, the setup freezes somewhere along the way and the installation fails. When IOMMU is off, it won't even boot.

I've circumvented this by adding `iommu=pt iommu=1` to the end of the line where syslinux defines the boot image. After the installation I have to add the same kernel options to GRUB. This procedure makes the OS usable but I noticed some performance issues. The window animations are not smooth, scrolling in any internet browser is laggy and generally, it *feels* sub-optimal.

Has anyone experienced something similar?

Answer (score 0):

I had problems after upgrading my mother board to GA-970A-UD3P with a FX-4300 cpu - no USB, no internet etc.  I changed the bios setting to disable iommu and changed grub to read 'GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="iommu=soft"'.  This solved the problems in Ubuntu 14.10 but 15.04 still doesn't see the network although the USB mouse works.  Windows 10 had no problems with the upgrade.

For info: I triple boot Ubuntu 14.10; Ubuntu 15.04 and windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

It is reasonable to have performance issues, because "iommu=1" is the same with "iommu=on".

You may use "iommu=pt" or "iommu=soft", but use only one of them & after modifying with "sudo nano /etc/default/grub" with  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="iommu=pt" or GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="iommu=soft", proceed with "sudo update-grub" and reboot.